# Writing user input to a file

Tags: php, file-io

The below code doesn't create info.txt file and dies:
How can i show error codes in such case - appending to die command with "."?

```
$MorF .= $name ." ". $family;
$MorF .="with username " . $user;
$MorF .="  and password " . $pass;
$MorF .=" lives in " . $city;

$fileLines = "";
if (file_exists("info.txt"))
{
    $fileLines = file_get_contents("info.txt");
    $fileNewLines = $fileLines . $MorF . "\n";
    file_put_contents("info.txt", $fileNewLines);   
}
else
{
    die("Something went wrong !");
}
```

Comment: @Skaffman I realise the arabic might have looked like perl, but it's still PHP :)

Comment: Arabic chars changed to English for u to read easier

Comment: But...why not use a database?  That way the data is retrievable, searchable, editable and other ...ables to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try...catch` so you have some debugging information upon encountering an error.  Also, not sure if this is intentional, but your logic there has the script fail when the file does not already exist.  I've included an allowance for that condition here, but I am not certain if that was your intent.

```
  try {
    // do not continue if file does not exist
    if (!file_exists("info.txt"))
       die('Something went wrong: file does not exist');
    // append the data to the file
    $fileLines = file_get_contents("info.txt");
    $fileNewLines = $fileLines . $MorF . "\n";
    file_put_contents("info.txt", $MorF);       
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    // handle an error 
    die("Something went wrong: ".$e->getMessage());
  }
```